# User visualize others folders with permission edit and limited acess

Tags: sharepoint-permissions

I am new to SharePoint, and I want to restrict a user A to his own folder only, enabling to send files, delete and update.

Today the user A sees folder B, C and so on, they are seeing each other users folders, they are associated with a group with edit and limited access.

How can I correct this behavior and limit to see only his own folder?

Answer (score 0):

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782
And: https://www.process.st/how-to/restrict-access-to-a-folder-in-sharepoint/

Stop Inheriting Permissions: Access your SharePoint site and navigate to the folder you want to restrict. Select the checkbox beside the folder name. Click ‘Manage Access’ from the top context menu. Click ‘Stop Inheriting Permissions’. This stops new users from getting access.

Set Permissions for the Folder: Choose specific users or groups from your organization. Deny all other new users. Authorize them with the right permissions based on custom roles. Choose ‘read’, ‘write’, and ‘full control’ permissions. Read-only viewers can view documents. People with writing permissions can edit, rename, move, and delete documents.

Add Users to the Restricted Folder: Adding users and groups to the restricted folder further ensures that only intended users have access.